# How to append object inside an object without overwriting and using storage.sync.set?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How can I append object inside an object without overwriting AND using storage.sync.set?

```
let presentationtitle = 'Test presentation 123'  

let variable = { 
       presentations: {
          [presentationtitle] : {
              duration: '00:00:00',
          }
       },
    };

chrome.storage.sync.get('presentations', function(data) {
  
if (typeof data.presentations === 'undefined') {
    // if not set then set it 
    let extensionsettings = { 
       presentations: {
          [presentationtitle] : {
          }
       },
        general: {
          setting1: true,
          setting2: false
        },
      };

    chrome.storage.sync.set(extensionsettings, () => {
          }); 
    } 
else {
    chrome.storage.sync.get('presentations', function(data) {

    if (typeof data.presentations[presentationtitle] === 'undefined') {
    // if not set then set it 
        
    // APPEND OBJECT but it overwrites
     let presentationtitlesave = { 
       presentations: {
          [presentationtitle] : {
              duration: '00:00:00',
          }
       },
       };
          
    chrome.storage.sync.set(presentationtitlesave, () => {
          });
    }
    // I need to APPEND instead of OVERWRITING
    
        });
    }
```

I also tried below which also overwrites

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({
              presentations: {[presentationtitle]: {duration: '00:00:00',} },
            }, () => {
            });
```

Do I need to first use sync.get to temporarily store it in a variable in order to append that and always overwrite storage with the new appended variable instead of appending it in storage?

Comment: "Do I need to first use sync.get to temporarily store it in a variable in order to append that and always overwrite storage with the new appended variable instead of appending it in storage?" --- Yes, that's how chrome.storage works.

Comment: Or you can store each presentation separately. `chrome.storage.sync.set({[presentationtitle]: '00:00:00'});`

Comment: Thanks, I will need to extract all presentations in future thus  I thought it's probably easier to keep them within a dedicated object `presentations`.  Can I utilise the `...data` approach to append? I tried `data = {...data,
                 
                 presentations: {
          [presentationtitle] : {
              duration: '00:00:00',
          }
       },
       };
           `

Comment: I think I figured it out using `data.presentations = {...data.presentations, [presentationtitle] : {duration:'00:00:00'} };`